# Use of pwgen with sha1 to create recreatable passwords

Tags: passwords, sha

I'm looking at using Theodore T'so's pwgen (on linux/ubuntu) with its sha1 (-H) feature to generate passwords that I should be able to recreate later using the same file and seed.

I briefly looked to see what alternatives there might be if this particular app (pwgen in unix) is not available to me at any point. Is this a valid consideration? Is there an alternative application that will let me recreate the same password (given the same file and seed of course)?

Whilst this might to some extent be a unix/ubuntu app availability question, I want to hear from security folk on the pros and cons of this approach, hence this question on this forum.

Comment: What's wrong with a password manager?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the context, which you do not specify. You want to be able to recreate the passwords for some reason; depending on that reason, inability to do it without a Linux machine at hand may or may not be a problem. In any case, the [README file](https://github.com/jbernard/pwgen/blob/master/README.md) points at some ports to other systems, e.g. for [Windows](http://pwgen-win.sourceforge.net/); moreover, chances are that the original "for Unix" pwgen could be compiled and executed without any change on a Windows machine with the help of [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). And you always have the option to run a VM (e.g. with [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)), install a minimal Unix-like system in it, and run pwgen on that.

When you create passwords deterministically from a *file* and a *seed* (that's what the `-H` option does with `pwgen`), then the resulting passwords are no stronger than the file and seed are secret. Typically you would use the target server name as seed, and the file as a secret (that way, you can derive multiple passwords for many sites, from a master secret file); if you can keep a file secret, you might be able to keep a *text file* secret. That text file would simply contain your passwords so far, added with a text editor. This might be a simpler model, and it abstracts away all considerations about portability of a specific application to various platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing every option that `pwgen` supports is a bit of work. But you can start simulating the behavoiour of

```
pwgen -s -H asd -y
```

with a simple bash script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
pw_digits="0123456789";
pw_uppers="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
pw_lowers="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
pw_symbols="!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~";
pw_ambiguous="B8G6I1l0OQDS5Z2";
pw_vowels="01aeiouyAEIOUY";

len="${1:-8}"
seed="${2:-pwgen}"
roundseed="$seed"
numpws=160

cset="${pw_digits}${pw_uppers}${pw_lowers}${pw_symbols}"
sum=""
rands=()

typeset -i idx

function reinit()
{
    sum="$( (dd if=asd bs=1 count=1024 2> /dev/null ; echo -n "$roundseed") | sha1sum | sed "s/ .*$//")"
    roundseed="$roundseed$seed"
    idx=0
    rands=($(echo $sum | sed "s/../0x& /g"))
}

reinit

for ((numpw = 0; numpw < "$numpws"; numpw++)) ; do
    valid=0
    while [[ $valid -eq 0 ]] ; do
        pw=""
        for ((char = 0; char < "$len"; char++)) ; do
            if [[ $idx -ge ${#rands[@]} ]] ; then
                reinit
            fi
            typeset -i randidx
            randidx=${rands[$idx]}
            randidx=$(( $randidx * ${#cset} / 256 ))
            pw="$pw${cset:$randidx:1}"
            idx=$(($idx+1))
        done
        if [[ "$pw" =~ [A-Z] ]] && [[ "$pw" =~ [0-9] ]] ; then
            for ((ckp = 0; ckp < ${#pw}; ckp++)) ; do
                for ((cks = 0; cks < ${#pw_symbols}; cks++)) ; do
                    [[ "${pw_symbols:$cks:1}" = "${pw:$ckp:1}" ]] && valid=1
                done
            done
        fi
    done
    echo -n "$pw "
    [[ $(($numpw % 8)) -eq 7 ]] && echo
done
[[ $(($numpw % 8)) -eq 0 ]] || echo
```

Of course this is *way* slower that in C...

You can give the number of characters per password as the first parameter and the seed as the second parameter.